# Strange behavior of CGPoint

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cgpoint

I have CGPoint in interface section of my class

```
@interface MyClass ()
{
    CGPoint point;
}
```

In code I tried to set value to it

```
point = CGPointMake(1, 3);
```

but result is (0,1)

another example:

```
CGPoint qwe = CGPointMake(10, 20);
point = qwe;
```

result: qwe(10,20), point(0,10)

The same problem with ALL variables that declare in interface (CGFloat, NSNumber..)

WTF?

Comment: How are you determining the contents of the point? Debugging or printing out? CGPoint is a struct, so I doubt this is a problem with ARC.

Comment: Definitely nothing to do with ARC, I have edited the question to remove this.

Comment: >> How are you determining the contents of the point?
By debugging.

Comment: it's would be a good idea to use float for parameters: `CGPointMake(1.0,3.0);` yes compiler should handle your code properly but why even give it a chance to go wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you log them to the console using `NSStringFromCGPoint(point);`? If not, try it.
Probalby you oversee something. A simple assignment of a CGPoint won't fail regardsless of beeing a local variable or an instance variable.

Comment: Dont know why, but the problem is in debugger. All printed in console has valid values. Thank you!